# Can't jump while using View Navigation Walk

Tags: 3d-view, camera, shortcut, navigation

I'm using View Navigation Walk and the jump functionality is strange. I press <kbd>spacebar</kbd> but instead of jumping I go flying to whatever surface is straight ahead of me. It's more like a "hookshot" or "grapple gun" maneuver than a jump. Actually, I think this is the Teleport feature. But if that's the case, what key is "jump" mapped to?

[image]

When I search for "jump" in the Keymap section of Preferences nothing relevant turns up.

Answer (score 1):

In Preferences, search shortcuts by name and look in **3D View** > **3D View (Global)** > (scroll way down) **View3D Walk Modal**

[image: View3D Walk Modal key bindings]

It's odd that it doesn't appear in search results when typing "walk" or "jump".

The default jump key is <kbd>V</kbd>, but can of course be reassigned.

It may also be worth mentioning that once in the Walk Modal, <kbd>Tab</kbd> toggles gravity, <kbd>Esc</kbd> resets the camera to its original position, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> commits the new camera position.